# Retrieve All Subscriber where Add Method is 'Import'

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, list, sql, subscriber

I would like to retrieve All Subscriber from a List where the Add Method is 'Import'.

I tryed do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE ListID = 2677 AND addMethod = 'Import'
```

But I retrieved nothing.

If I try to get All Subscriber where Status is active it works and i got a result.

```
SELECT * FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE ListID = 2677 AND status = 'active'
```

This seems like  a basic query. What I doing wrong? Or one could give me suggestions to get the result on another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try inspecting what addMethod values you get from _ListSubscribers; it could be that the values are being logged differently for your listid .

e.g.

```
SELECT 
AddMethod
FROM _ListSubscribers WHERE ListID = 2677
Group by AddMethod
```

It may be how the values are returned, so once you find the values you can adjust your query.

You could then try a Like Method too :

```
SELECT * FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE ListID = 2677 AND addMethod Like '%Import%'
```

Without knowing how your contact records were imported to the list, we are only assuming you did it by Import